# Solr indexversion and replicatable index version are different

Tags: solr, replication, solrj, slave

I am using solrJ to add documents to solr server. 
I have a master/slave setup. After indexing, i do a commit through `http://URL/update?commit=true` so that i am able to do the search in the master node. But for the replication, when i see the indexversion details using replication?command=details, i see the indexverion and the replicatableindexversion are different.

```
`<arr name="commits">
<lst>
<long name="indexVersion">1346928051888</long>
<long name="generation">1907</long>
<arr name="filelist"></arr>
</lst>
</arr>
<str name="isMaster">true</str>
<str name="isSlave">false</str>
<long name="indexVersion">1346928051888</long>
<long name="generation">1907</long>
<lst name="master"><arr name="replicateAfter"><str>commit</str>
<str>startup</str></arr>
<str name="replicationEnabled">true</str>
<long name="replicatableIndexVersion">1346928046763</long>
<long name="replicatableGeneration">1</long></lst>
</lst>`

Because of this the slave is not replicating the commited document.


Here is the code i used for solrJ to add documents
Collection<SolrInputDocument> docs = new ArrayList<SolrInputDocument>();
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.add(FIELDS);
docs.add(doc);

SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.add(FIELDS);
docs.add(doc);

SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.add(FIELDS);
docs.add(doc);

server.add(docs);
server.commit();
```

Am I missing anything over here? Any help is much appreciated.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would try to avoid putting together replication after commit & startup. It's causing some issues 
Try replication after commit only.

```
<requestHandler name="/replication" class="solr.ReplicationHandler" >
    <lst name="master">

        <str name="replicateAfter">commit</str>     
        <str name="confFiles">schema.xml,stopwords.txt,elevate.xml</str>
        <str name="commitReserveDuration">00:00:10</str>
    </lst>
     <str name="maxNumberOfBackups">1</str> 
</requestHandler>
```

Is it working like this ?